# Windows 10 Start Menu & Cortana etc won't open after a while

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, cortana

After an undetermined amount of time my Start Menu & Cortana & Volume Widget etc won't open. A restart fixes the proble temporarily.

I have tried:

the powershell script (it freezes on a certain task actually)
the registry edit
uninstalling dropbox and reinstalling without the autostart
creating a new user (I created the new user when the Start Menu wasn't able to open, then switched to that use and the Start Menu still wouldn't open)

I don't have any anti virus installed apart from Windows Defender

My startup programs are practically non existent (intel graphics apps and touchpad software)

I've run out of solutions to try, and googling for the problem seems to mostly bring up some really outdated info.

Is anyone aware of any recent solutions to this problem that I haven't mentioned?

Thanks

Other notes:
Windows 10 Pro 64bit
I rarely shut down, just close the lid on my laptop which sets the laptop to "sleep"
The problem happened when I used Classic Shell also, iirc

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Classic Shell, and I've had no issues with the Start Menu for days. In fact, Cortana and the Volume widget are refusing to load so the problem has still happened, but Classic Shell is a perfectly good workaround for me